# JavaScript Login form not detecting authentication code

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have simple login form on my website. I am using firebase authentication to authenticate users. So far I can create a user successfully with the signup form. However, when I try to log them in with the created credentials nothing happens. Not even when I press the login button. There should be an error message on the login form if you try and click submit without entering any data into the fields but even that does not work. Could it be a getElementById problem? Kindly help me out. **PS:** You can test out logging in with a user I created: **username:** test@google.com **password:** helloworld

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.4/css/bulma.min.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>My Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <!--Login   -->
    <section>
      <div class="hero is-fullheight">
        <div class="hero-body is-justify-content-center is-align-items-center">
          <div class="columns is-flex is-flex-direction-column box">
            <div class="column">
              <h1 class="title">Please enter your credentials</h1>
              <label for="email">Email</label>
              <input id="login-email" class="input is-primary" type="text" placeholder="Email address">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <label for="Name">Password</label>
              <input id="login-pwd" class="input is-primary" type="password" placeholder="Password">
              <a href="forget.html" class="is-size-7 has-text-primary">forget password?</a>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <button id="login-btn" class="button is-primary is-fullwidth" type="submit">Login</button>
            </div>
            <div class="has-text-centered">
              <p class="is-size-7"> Don't have an account? <a href="index.html" class="has-text-primary">Sign up</a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <!-- Firebase Auth -->
  <script type="module" src="index.js">
    //FIREBASE AUTH
    // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
    import {
      initializeApp
    } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.13.0/firebase-app.js";
    import {
      getDatabase,
      set,
      ref,
      update
    } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.13.0/firebase-database.js";
    import {
      getAuth,
      createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
      signInWithEmailAndPassword
    } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.13.0/firebase-auth.js";
    // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyAalz5fFuOOG6_EZVFIO-hJRA2Sw1Yyg2A",
      authDomain: "lost-and-found-system-67568.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://lost-and-found-system-67568-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "lost-and-found-system-67568",
      storageBucket: "lost-and-found-system-67568.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "32608786023",
      appId: "1:32608786023:web:6aea01187ecb53ce6a66c2"
    };

    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const database = getDatabase(app);
    const auth = getAuth();

    signup.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

      var username = document.getElementById('signup-user').value;
      var email = document.getElementById('signup-email').value;
      var schoolID = document.getElementById('signup-id').value;
      var password = document.getElementById('signup-pwd').value;

      createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
          // Signed in 
          const user = userCredential.user;

          set(ref(database, 'user/' + user.id), {
            username: username,
            email: email
          })
          alert('User Created!');
          // ...
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          const errorCode = error.code;
          const errorMessage = error.message;

          alert('Error!');
          // ..
        });
    });

    //login section
    login-btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      var email = document.getElementById('login-email').value;
      var password = document.getElementById('login-pwd').value;

      signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
          // Signed in 
          const user = userCredential.user;

          const dt = new Date();
          update(ref(database, 'user/' + user.id), {
            last_login: dt,
          })

          alert('User logged In!');
          // ...
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          const errorCode = error.code;
          const errorMessage = error.message;
        });

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `login-btn` is not defined and is also not a valid variable name. You're missing something like `const loginBtn = document.getElementById("login-btn")`. You should do the same with `signup`

Comment: @Phil Okay so I tried and changed the variable name of login button to just `login` but it still didn't work. The `signup` id for the sign up part of the form is also not defined but it still works. That is why I was wondering why it was not working with the login button in the same way.